# FluentAssertions .Pass declaration

Tags: .net, .net-core, fluent-assertions

After performing a test, we typically do an `Assert.True(someCondition)`.  When a condition check isn't necessary and just completion of the test is sufficient, I end a test with `Assert.Pass()`.

I'm using `FluentAssertions` and have been doing `true.Should().BeTrue();`.  That is starting to feel more like a hack and not in the correct spirit of the library.

Is there some other Fluent syntax I could use to accomplish `.Pass()` intention?

-Update: Based on feedback, there is nothing wrong with using `.Pass()` from `XUnit` or `NUnit` when using primarily `FluentAssertions`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't any equivalent to `Assert.Pass()` in Fluent Assertions.
`true.Should().BeTrue()` is a tautology and a weaker statement than `Assert.Pass()`. So between those two I would continue using `Assert.Pass()`.

Another way to explicitly state in code that running to completion is success, is saying that no exceptions should occur.

```
// Arrange
var subject = ...

// Act
var act = () => subject.CalculateTaxes();

// Assert
act.Should().NotThrow<Exception>();
```

For more examples on how to assert on exceptions, see https://fluentassertions.com/exceptions/.

A third way is to simply abandon the requirement of an explicit assertion, this can e.g. be captured in the method name, e.g. `calculating_taxes_does_not_throw`.

Comment: We are moving to `FluentAssertions` so `Assert.Pass()` isn't an option anymore.  Also these are more integrations tests so if step1(), step2(), step3() all work an no exceptions are thrown, we should be good.

`true.Should().NotThrow<Exception>()` is better conceptually, but of course isn't exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: If you continue using NUnit as the test framework, there's nothing wrong in using `Assert.Pass()`. Fluent Assertions isn't a complete replacement, but an addition.